# constructing data-type instances from CSV

Tags: haskell, csv, algebraic-data-types

I have CSV data (inherited - no choice here) which I need to use to create data type instances in Haskell. parsing CSV is no problem - tutorials and APIs abound.

Here's what 'show' generates for my simplified trimmed-down test-case:

```
JField {fname = "cardNo", ftype = "str"} (string representation)
```

I am able to do a read to convert this string into a JField data record. My CSV data is just the values of the fields, so the CSV row corresponding to JField above is:

```
cardNo, str
```

and I am reading these in as List of string ["cardNo", "str"]

So - it's easy enough to brute-force the exact format of "string representation" (but writing Java or python-style string-formatting in Haskell isn't my goal here).

I thought of doing something like this (the first List is static, and the second list would be read file CSV) :

```
let stp1 = zip ["fname = ", "ftype ="] ["cardNo", "str"]
```

resulting in

```
[("fname = ","cardNo"),("ftype =","str")]
```

and then concatenating the tuples - either explicitly with ++ or in some more clever way yet to be determined.

This is my first simple piece of code outside of tutorials, so I'd like to know if this seems a reasonably Haskellian way of doing this, or what clearly better ways there are to build just this piece:
    fname = "cardNo", ftype = "str"

Not expecting solutions (this is not homework, it's a learning exercise), but rather critique or guidelines for better ways to do this. Brute-forcing it would be easy but would defeat my objective, which is to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be way off, but wouldn't a `map` be better here?  I guess I'm assuming that you read the file in with each row as a `[String]` i.e.

```
field11, field12
field21, field22
```

etc.

You could write

```
map (\[x,y] -> JField {fname = x, ftype = y}) data
```

where `data` is your input.  I think that would do it.

Comment: thx. As to possibly being way off, at this point I don't know really, so I will try it and see what I get

Comment: Well, my confusion comes down to what you're trying to do, and what you're doing it with.
data has to have type [[String]], that is, it's a list of all the rows.
And it returns a list of JFields (type [JField])... is that what you were looking for?

Comment: "returns a list of JFields (type [JField])... "correct - the suggestion is spot on and gives me something to work with. I was not looking for copy-paste code, but understanding; your answer helped. thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the value of the fname field (say, in the variable `fn`) and the value of the ftype field (in `ft`), just do `JField {fname=fn, ftype=ft}`.  For non-String fields, just insert a `read` where appropriate.

Comment: thanks. I will look into this, but right now I'm not seeing List (or Map) processing where I expect to see it, though I do appreciate the answer.